# he found people who

Tags: sentence-construction

> He found people who are at once more resilient and more vulnerable than their peers in the rich world.

I think "who" is redundant, change it to:

He found (that) people are at once more resilient and more vulnerable than their peers in the rich world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct, but mean something different.

"He found people **who** are ..." limits the descriptor to a specific group.

"He found that people are..." applies the descriptor to all people.

In the second option, if the speaker wanted to limit this to less than all, change of the verb to "could be" would give the application definition of potential for those who might fit the criteria.